# How to append page with ITextSharp on existing PDF

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation

I am a bit confused about the structure of ITextSharp API, because is not clear to me which object I should use (among many) to append pages to an existing document.
It's important to me to write an implace document, so i don't do as many example show, basically i don't take a source PDF and create a new one modified, but just open it with a writer and try to append a new page.

Here the piece of code i use to try to append a page to an existing PDF, such code is called in a loop many times :

```
        using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4))
        {
            using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append)) )
            {
                document.Open();
                document.NewPage();
                
                iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bitmap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                image.ScaleToFit(document.PageSize);
                image.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                image.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_TOP;

                document.Add(image);

                document.Close();
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
```

First time the code is executed thing works fine (except for image absolute position, for some reason the image does not start at the beginning of page).
After the first execution then, the new page created, does not append to the existing document, but replace the previous page, and that behaviour really puzzle me (I expected a new page will be appended).

I think there is something I miss about how the library should be used.

Comment: A `Document`/`PdfWriter` pair writes a new PDF document from scratch. Due to the use of `FileMode.Append` you get a concatenation of multiple PDFs. Such a _concatenation of multiple PDFs_ is no valid PDF, though. Thus, PDF viewers will try to repair it and will probably get what you describe, the most recently appended PDF.

Comment: There are two principal ways in iTextSharp (versions 4 and 5) to add to an existing PDF: either you use a `PdfReader`/`PdfStamper` pair or you first create the addition using a `Document`/`PdfWriter` pair as a separate, temporary PDF and then merge the old and the temporary PDF to a new PDF using a `Document`/`PdfCopy` pair. Which option works best for you, depends on the kind of additions and other requirements of your project.

Comment: Newer iText for .NET versions (versions 7 and 8) feature an overhauled API that allows by means of a `PdfReader`/`PdfWriter`/`PdfDocument` triple arbitrary additions to existing PDFs.

Comment: @mkl great explanation thanks, so i understand why i see the size (on disk) grow, but cant see the data. I will try to proceede as you explain to me (reader+stamper) , thanks again